# Visial Studio - MS Teams - Auto Email Changes to Spreadsheet - Is this possible?

Tags: visual-studio, microsoft-teams

Visual Studio 2017
Microsoft Teams

Scenario:

Within Teams we have a team with a tab that contains a spreadsheet. Users can enter information w/ a new number and the name of the person responsible etc.

Is it possible that when this item is entered that an email can automatically be sent to the person responsible from within Teams?

I have done some initial research and so far I do see where you can create apps BUT I just would like to know if what I am proposing is possible and if so would it be a monumental undertaking or shouldn't be too difficult.

Any thoughts/feedback appreciated,

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There are actually two problems to solve here. One, how to detect that something happened in Excel. Two, to take action on that event and send email.

For both of these, you can create Excel macros using VBA (transforming the file from xlsx to xslm). XSLM files require the full Excel client though and don't run well on the web version of Excel. I can't think of another way to do it using Excel.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - if I understand correctly I think I can just ignore the Teams part and just focus in on the Excel (VBA) - I will try that and see what happens